# <stdin>:1: FutureWarning in Python (convert JSON to EXCEL)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd, xlwt

I am convert json to excel with python, but had error like this. How i fix it??

Error :
**:1: FutureWarning: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas. This is the only engine in pandas that supports writing in the xls format. Install openpyxl and write to an xlsx file instead. You can set the option io.excel.xls.writer to 'xlwt' to silence this warning. While this option is deprecated and will also raise a warning, it can be globally set and the warning suppressed.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
df.to_excel('modified.xls', index=False)
```

you should:

```
df.to_excel('modified.xlsx', index=False)
```